# IndexError : List Out of Range

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, rfid

Due to using NTAG213 and MFRC522 (RFID), so I read the database from NTAG213. So there's something that I changed, and you can see that the problem may in the "num_to_dec" but I confused how to change it. This is how the error looks:

[image]

And this is my [code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19sQbkXdTVh1fmNc1WK5QXdsOtrvqSqRR)

so this is the code i tried:

```
   def uid_to_num(self, uid):
       n = 0
       for i in range (0, 8): #due to ntag213 have 7 bytes UID
           n = n*256 + uid[i] #error
   return n
```

you can see in the image that I attached, and the error indicates to that line.

Comment: whats is  `uid`?, provide a [mcve]

Comment: according to what I see, uid has only 5 elements and not 8

Comment: Please, copy the error message instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: Try using `for digit in uid:`, then `n = n*256 + digit` which should avoid any `IndexError`s (assuming `uid` is something iterable).

Comment: u just posted a link to a google repository in which the standart library for this reader is. u did not code anything on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your uid length is less than 8 and so it is getting out of index error. 
will `int(uid)` work for you?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score 0):

I am also using MFRC522 reader and sometime this error arises for code in my card. Since whatever you write in code in `Write.py` file is not suitable with `Read.py file`. 
So Write card again and use that card according to inputs.

If you write new data:

```
id:
time:
```

but your Read file not according to that

```
print (id)
print(text)
```

note: write card code again then apply in Read file